# The select2 option is not working. How to resolve it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, jquery-select2

I am working in asp.net core. I am using typescript. I am using select2.

HTML:-

```
  <select multiple id="e1" class="js-example-basic-multiple js-states form-control">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
  <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
  <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
  </select>
```

Script:-

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();
    });
 </script>
```

css and js:-

```
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

This is my code. I write the html code and script in partial view. I add the css and js file for select2 in layout page.

I get output like this:

[image]

The select2 is not referred here. But it is added in the project.

Can anyone suggest what mistake I have done?

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: Hi Arg0n, There is no errors related to this.

Comment: Can you share this on e.g. jsfiddle for us to test?

Comment: In jsfiddle, it works...

Comment: Then you got some other problems with your code. Did you e.g. include a library multiple times?

Comment: I added library only once

Comment: Post your whole code. The snippets you have posted are fine, must be another error

Comment: I use select2 inside of dialog. I check by using select2 outside of dialog. It works. But inside of dialog , it cannot works.